# kentico 9 cmsdesk system error after admin login

Tags: kentico

This is a fun one. Just moved my build to the dev environment. I'm getting a system error when trying to access the CMS Desk. I can't see the event log to trouble shoot. How i can go about finding possible issues. I had admin access to the DEV VM, but not the SQL box.

I'm currently on hot fix 30, and my local dev is fine.

I've noticed that the Kentico CMS Health Monitor and Scheduler services didn't start. Manualy starting these gives an error.

When i attempted to login in from the VM, i get this error.

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'CMSAdminControls_Basic_OrderByControl' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a8d48e58\742913f6\assembly\dl3\864636c6\8ed0e2be_5525d201\CMSApp.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a8d48e58\742913f6\App_Web_orderbycontrol.ascx.cffe6b5c.9lvruqx-.dll'

Source Error:

Line 87:                                     
Line 88:                                     
Line 89:                                         
Line 91:

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico9\CMS\CMSAdminControls\UI\UniGrid\Controls\AdvancedExport.ascx    Line: 89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Kentico was setup as a Web Site, rather than a Web Application. Just as easy to nuke, and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean (delete) content from that temporary folder.

Comment: That didn't help. I suspect this VM has kentico as a Web Site, while my local dev is a Web App.